# How to clear entries in tkinter after clicking submit button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Tkinter to make a user input form and take values from users and storing the values in a database when clicked on the submit button. I want to clear all the fields from the entry widgets after clicking the submit button so that the values get stored in the database as well as the entry widgets clear out so that the user can again fill the details. I tried the delete(0;'end') command but it did not work.
Following is my code:

```
def database():
    customer_name = name.get()
    mobile_no = num.get()
    email_id = mail_id.get()
    address = addr.get()

    result = {
            "Customer Name":customer_name,
            "Mobile":mobile_no,
            "Email ID":email_id,
            "Address":address
    }

    print(result)
    db.Customer_Info.insert_one(result)
    print('Value Inserted')
    client.close()


##Creating tkinter window
def main_page():
    
    global window
    window = Tk()
    window.title('Products')
    window.geometry('400x500')

    global name,uname,mob,num,mail_id,addr
    name = StringVar()
    num = IntVar()
    num.set('')
    mail_id = StringVar()
    addr = StringVar()

    Label(window,text = 'HN Organics',background = 'green',
        foreground = 'white',font = ('Arial',20)).grid(column = 0,
        row = 0, padx = 120, pady =25)

    Label(window ,text = "Name").grid()
    uname = Entry(window,textvariable = name).grid()

    Label(window ,text = "Mobile No.").grid()
    mob = Entry(window,textvariable = num).grid()

    Label(window ,text = "Email ID").grid()
    mail = Entry(window,textvariable = mail_id).grid()

    Label(window ,text = "Address").grid()
    addr1 = Entry(window,textvariable = addr).grid()

    Button(window,text = 'Submit',command = database).grid()

    window.mainloop()
main_page()
```

When the submit button is clicked the values are stored in the database but I want the entries to clear as well after being stored in the database. How do I do that??
I tried using name.delete(0.'end') / name.delete(0.'END') and even name.delete(0.'Tkinter.END') but it shows that there is no attribute delete.

Comment: The error you received might be because you used `Entry(...).grid(...)`. Put both of these in two different lines and then the error might vanish ;)

Comment: I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Check my answer out

Comment: and please include the full error to the Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `set('')` command in the database function after you store the values and it will clear out the entries so that the user can fill details again.
Just add:

```py
name.set('')
num.set('')
mail_id.set('')
addr.set('')
```

after `client.close()`

Answer (score 0):

Don't put quotations around END.
try name.delete (0, END).
Delete is part of normal tkinter library so should work.

Comment: It shows the following error :
AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'delete'